# Kernel 4.15.0-48 causes NVIDIA Persistence Daemon problem during boot

Tags: boot, nvidia, kernel, updates, persistence

A few days ago kernel 4.15.0-48 got installed by system update on my Ubuntu 18.04. Since then the system will hang during boot, caused by NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.

[image]

If I select the previous kernel 4.15.0-47 in boot manager options the system runs normally, so the problem is caused by an incompatibility introduced by the new kernel.

The computer's hardware specs are: Intel Core i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz × 8, 16 GB RAM and GeForce GTX 750 Ti/PCIe/SSE2.

Do you have any ideas about how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue needed to install nvidia-driver-390 after purging all the older drivers ...
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-390
sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-390

have audio issues after but at least the system boots